# Creating a function that returns a promise and handle the callback

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, promise

Here is my code:

```
function getUserRatingsSorted(userIds) {
  return Promise.all(userIds.map(id => {
    return admin.database().ref().child('users').child(id).on('value', (s) => {
      const user = s.val();
      user.id = id;
      return user;
    });
  }));
}
function prepareGameForStart(userIds) {
  getUserRatingsSorted(userIds)
  .then((users) => evaluateUsersByRatings(users))
  .then((playerAndRatings) => distributePlayersInTeams(playerAndRatings))
  .then(notification.sendPushNotificationTo('Teams have been selected', 'Log in to your group to see your team', userIds))
  .catch((error) => {
    console.log(error);
  });
}
```

When I log the ***users*** in the first **then** I get

> [ [Function], [Function], [Function], [Function] ]

and it gets triggered before the users are retrieved from the firebase. So if I `console.log(user)` in the `getUserRatingsSorted` function they get printed after the ***users*** are logged. For me this doesn't sound right since things in the promise should be printed then things in the **then**. I believe I am doing something wrong in creating a promise function.

Comment: Does `.on()` return a promise?

Comment: I see a callback, so probably not - if that's the case, you'll have to construct a `Promise` from it first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[on()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Reference#on) doesn't return a promise (as you can see from the linked API docs).  It listens indefinitely, until you remove the listener.  Instead, use [once()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Reference#once) to perform a single query that returns a promise to indicate that the query is complete, containing a snapshot of the data.

Comment: Yes this resolved it for me. Once is what i need. Thanks a lot everybody.

Comment: If this answer addressed your problem, please mark it as correct.